# Using library gives unknown reference error

Tags: c, gcc, libraries

I am currently creating a C library to accept input(similar to scanf), but after moving all the necessary files to the relevant places, this error is seen when I type this command (`gcc main.c -o main.exe -linput`)

```
undefined reference to `getInput
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have moved the C file and the header file to the GCC include folder, and I have moved `libinput.a` to the lib folder.
I have also done the same thing with another library I made, but that works fine.

After some further digging I found out that when I right-click on the function "getinput" and click "go to definition", it goes to the `input.c` file instead of the `input.h`. In the other libraries, it redirects me to the `library.h` file and not the `library.c` file. This might be the problem but I have no idea of how to fix it.

Note- running `gcc main.c libinput.a` works while having `libinput.a` in the same directory, but I
would prefer `gcc main.c -o main.exe -linput`(without having it in the same directory,
similar to how other libraries work). Having `input.c` and `input.h` in the same directory
and then linking it also works.
Environment - VS code on windows 10

Here is my code so far:
`input.h`

```c
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

void getInput(char *str, ...);

#endif
```

`main.c`(an example code where I am using the library)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <input.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = NULL;
    getInput("{s}", &s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Edit - I fixed it by moving the files to the following places

libinput.a = D:\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0

input.c and input.h = D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include

Comment: The prototype in a header is a declaration. The definition is where you provide the code for the function. Therefore it is correct if "goto definition" goes to the C file. Opening the declaration in the header is a fallback in case no definition is visible for VS code

Comment: Why did you move a C file of your library into the include folder? That's not an include file.

Comment: Where did you move `libinput.a`? Can you use other library files from that same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell the linker to search other directories with `-L searchdir`.  gcc will pass that option through to the linker.

Comment: Do you know the reason why I don't need to do that for other libraries though?

Comment: @workwork because there are default search directories for libraries. If you put your library somewhere else you need to add that path to command line. To check default search directories, you can use `gcc -print-search-dirs`

Comment: @Gerhardh I put the `input.c` and the `input.h` file in `D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`
and I put the `libinput.a` file in `D:\mingw64\lib`
I have done the same thing for another library I made, that works fine without these errors. However this one gives me errors

Now I moved it to one of the directories given in the command you told me to use, and that seemed to fix it. Thanks a lot. But it is definitely weird I didn't need to do this for the other libraries

Comment: Do you use those other libs in the same project or in some other project? If you can use them you must have added the `-L` option somewhere. And then it would also work your your `libinput.a`. I assume you did that in another project where you have that option and in your current project you don't.

Comment: @Gerhardh I did it in another project, and I didn't need to put the -L for that. 
Is there a way for me to enable that option you speak of?

Comment: I am speaking of that option mentioned in this answer. You need to add to your compiler/linker command line